# cant build xamarin ios apps on jenkins with msbuild

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to create a ci for our iOS apps. I'm using jenkins as the ci tool on a macbook.
I'm building the ipa with msbuild running on master node.

Building directly from command line on the machine works + from visual studio GUI.

This is how I run my msbuild command:

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:IpaPackageDir="." /t:Build /p:OutputPath="." /p:IpaPackageName=myapp.ipa /p:BuildIpa=True mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj
```

after 3 minutes of build, I get the following error:

```
(_CompileITunesMetadata target) -> 
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018: The "CompileITunesMetadata" task failed unexpectedly. [/Users/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace. [/Users/myuser/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018: Parameter name: path [/Users/myuser/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018:   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00016] in <92218043474744ea9d64d27064c35dcb>:0  [/Users/myuser/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018:   at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.CompileITunesMetadataTaskBase.Execute () [0x001ed] in <5fc761670f214242b2d9c8c4b0525b32>:0  [/Users/myuser/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(320,3): error MSB4018:   at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.CompileITunesMetadata.Execute () [0x0002a] in <5fc761670f214242b2d9c8c4b0525b32>:0  [/Users/myuser/.jenkins/workspace/Build-iOS/mycsprojfolder/mycsprojfile.csproj]
```

I need to generate an Ipa file so we can upload it to appstore later.

msbuild version is 16.9.0.22901

jenkins version is 2.289.1

anyone encountered this? couldn't find an answer for this.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you run it with sudo?

Comment: when running directly on machine terminal it didn't work without sudo, permissions problems

Comment: Have you see  this?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/jenkins-walkthrough#firewall-configuration

Comment: Hey, I disabled the firewall on my mac so this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: What action you did cause this error? Or it just happened  spontaneously？

Comment: I just started building the ci job so it never worked before. That's what im trying

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT do you have any idea? im still clueless :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem was priviliges to keychain.
I enabled access to keychain on my mac os and it built successfully.